Annotation Processor to generate class like lombok
Hi I'm starting study annotation processing in Java using gradle, follow multi project struct:
ROOT
|
|-sample  # contains main classes
|-annotation # annotations read by processor
|-processor # processor to generate code

I try to create a annotation to do like a lombok @Builder, I can generate a class in a build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java ... but if I try to generate class in same package in a annotated class but a build task fail saying I try to replace file
sample:
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "br.com.dio"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":annotation"))
    compileOnly(project(":annotation"))
    implementation(project(":processor"))
    annotationProcessor(project(":processor"))
}


processor:
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "br.com.dio"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val autoServiceVersion = "1.1.1"

dependencies {
    compileOnly("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:$autoServiceVersion")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:$autoServiceVersion")
    implementation("com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0")
}


annotation:
plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "br.com.dio"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}


settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "annotation-processor"
include("processor")
include("sample")
include("annotation")


follow my code:
public class BuilderProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation)) {
                Map<String, TypeMirror> fields =element.getEnclosedElements().stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getKind() == FIELD)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getSimpleName().toString(), Element::asType));
                final var packageName = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getPackageOf(element).toString();
                final var className = element.getSimpleName().toString();
                final var fullNameClass = packageName + "." + className;
                final var typeSpec = new BuilderCreate().create(packageName, className, fields);
                var javaFile = JavaFile.builder(packageName, typeSpec)
                        .indent("    ")
                        .build();
                try(
                        var out = new PrintWriter(processingEnv.getFiler()
                                .createSourceFile(className)
                                .openWriter()
                        )
                ){
                    out.println(javaFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}


Are you saying your annotation processor (:processor) cannot find a class from the code it is processing (:sample)? If so, then that is to be expected, as the code being processed is currently being compiled. You have to use the Element and TypeMirror API.

@Slaw I added a snippet with code I create to try get class

You are trying to get the java.lang.Class associated with the annotated class currently being processed. This is not possible because the class has not been compiled yet. In other words, this is not a project configuration issue, but rather an API misuse issue. Use the javax.lang.model.* APIs to get the necessary information.

@Slaw I change my question, thank you for help to understand more about annotation processor, I almost finish my code :)

Annotation processing does not support modifying classes being processed. You can only generate new classes and/or resources. The way Lombok gets around this restriction is by "hacking" into the internals of the compiler to modify the ASTs. This makes implementations compiler-specific (e.g., Lombok only works with javac and ECJ, if I'm not mistaken; of course, those are the only two Java compilers I know of).

For close this question, I finished it create a builder class in another file using annotation processor, I thought how I could modify generate files and create a inner builder, like lombok, but in a comments Slaw help me to understand this is more complex ( and this is my first time using annotation processor) follow my final code:
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("br.com.dio.annotation.Builder")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_21)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class BuilderProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation)) {
                Map<String, TypeMirror> fields =element.getEnclosedElements().stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getKind() == FIELD)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getSimpleName().toString(), Element::asType));
                final var packageName = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getPackageOf(element).toString();
                final var className = element.getSimpleName().toString();
                final var builderName = className + "Builder";


                final var typeSpec = new BuilderCreate().create(packageName, className, builderName,fields);
                var javaFile = JavaFile.builder(packageName, typeSpec)
                        .indent("    ")
                        .build();
                try(
                        var out = new PrintWriter(processingEnv.getFiler()
                                .createSourceFile(className + "Builder")
                                .openWriter()
                        )
                ){
                    out.write(javaFile.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}


public class BuilderCreate {

    public TypeSpec create(final String packageName, final String className,
                           final String builderName,final Map<String, TypeMirror> fields){
        var generatedBuilderClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(builderName)
                .addModifiers(PUBLIC);

        fields.forEach((k, v) -> generatedBuilderClass.addField(TypeName.get(v), k, PRIVATE));
        fields.forEach((k, v) -> generatedBuilderClass.addMethod(buildBuilderSetter(
                        packageName,
                        builderName,
                        k,
                        TypeName.get(v))
                )
        );

        var buildMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("build")
                .addModifiers(PUBLIC)
                .returns(ClassName.get(packageName, className))
                .addStatement("var target = new $N()", className);

        fields.keySet().forEach(f -> buildMethod.addStatement(
                "target.set$N($N)",
                f.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + f.substring(1, f.length()),
                f)
        );
        buildMethod.addStatement("return target");

        return generatedBuilderClass.addMethod(buildMethod.build())
                .build();
    }

    private MethodSpec buildBuilderSetter(final String packageName, final String name, final String param, final TypeName type){
        return MethodSpec.methodBuilder(param)
                .addModifiers(PUBLIC)
                .returns(ClassName.get(packageName, name))
                .addParameter(type, param, FINAL)
                .addStatement("this.$N = $N", param, param)
                .addStatement("return this")
                .build();
    }

}


